# Convert int to string in a loop

Tags: java, string, loops, int

I want to ask how to convert an int value to string while runing in loop lets say i got an int value 1 at first running of loop then i got 2 and then 3 in the end i want a string with value "123"..
your answers would be very helpful.. THANKS

```
int sum = 57;
            int b = 4;
            String denada;
            while(sum != 0)
            {
                int j = sum % b;
                sum = sum / b
                denada = (""+j);
            }
```

Comment: Please give an example of what you want and what you actually get. Something like: When sum = 15, I want "6,7,8" to be printed.
BTW: denada is always "". You're not updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to convert an int value to string

`String.valueOf` function returns the string representation of an `int` value e.g. `String x = String.valueOf(2)` will store the `"2"` into `x`.

> lets say i got an int value 1 at first running of loop then i got 2
> and then 3 in the end i want a string with value "123"

Your approach is not correct. You need variables for:

1. Capturing the integer from the user e.g. `n` in the example given below.
2. Store the value of the appended result e.g. `sum` in the example given below.
3. Capturing the user's choice if he wants to continue e.g. `reply` in the example given below.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String reply = "Y";
        String sum = "";
        while (reply.toUpperCase().equals("Y")) {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            sum += n;
            System.out.print("More numbers[Y/N]?: ");
            reply = scan.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Appnded numbers: " + sum);
    }
}
```

**A sample run**

```
Enter an integer: 1
More numbers[Y/N]?: y
Enter an integer: 2
More numbers[Y/N]?: y
Enter an integer: 3
More numbers[Y/N]?: n
Appnded numbers: 123
```

The next thing you should try is to handle the exception which may be thrown when the user provides a non-integer input.

Comment: @saka1029 - The description he has provided is, `i got an int value 1 at first running of loop then i got 2 and then 3 in the end i want a string with value "123".`. I'll wait for his comment and update the answer if required.

Comment: thanks man it was very helpful the statement sum += n was the thing i didnt knew